# Unity NullReferenceException when creating a new project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get following error in Unity when creating a new project

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.ParseArguments.GetOrganizationNameFromData (System.String data) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/ParseArguments.cs:42)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.ParseArguments.CloudOrganization (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] args) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/ParseArguments.cs:24)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.DownloadRepository (System.String unityAccessToken, System.String[] commandLineArgs) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:63)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.DownloadRepository (System.String unityAccessToken) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:51)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.Execute (System.String unityAccessToken) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:43)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.RunOnceWhenAccessTokenIsInitialized () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:32)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at <e3d2e3f6a525465bbf8c67432a3cb6ef>:0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle a NullReference Exception c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638143/how-to-handle-a-nullreference-exception-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because of PlasticSCM(Version Control package).

Try to uninstall or update it in Package Manager.

And also can uncheck the [Version Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjGO1.png) toggle when you create a project.

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This error is probably coming from the Version Control package make sure its updated

- To update the version control package in your unity project

Window > Package Manager > (In the top left corner make sure you select Unity Registry from the packages drop down menu  ) > Search for Version Control and update it

If this didn't work try deleting the version control package then install it again

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me some time ago. It's a "false" error. The problem is the login session token expired. Don't worry, refreshing it is easy.

1. Close Unity Editor, keep Unity Hub open.
2. Sign out of Unity Hub (left-top icon)
3. Sign In Unity Hub
4. Start Unity Editor